# main.cpp:22:34: error: ‘xxxxxxx’ was not declared in this > scope

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I came across this error:

> main.cpp:22:34: error: ‘getTotalSystemMemory’ was not declared in this
>   scope

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Hello World! \n";

    cout << getTotalSystemMemory();

    return 0;
}

long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}
```

I assumed the the method ‘getTotalSystemMemory’ is in scope since it is within the same class

Comment: Re "since it is within the same class" - no it isn't, it's not in any class. It's in a namespace, so its scope begins when it's declared - in this case, *after* you try to use it in `main`.

Comment: The answers provided by both Luchian and Daniel are sufficiently good, but just two things I want to note: It would be enough to move the function `getTotalSystemMemory` above the main function. The compiler always reads from the top to the bottom. Second thing: what you have here is not a class, it's just a cpp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide at least a *declaration* before you use the function:

```
long getTotalSystemMemory(); //declaration

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //...
    cout << getTotalSystemMemory();
    //...
}

long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the function first with C/C++.

Put this before `main`

```
long getTotalSystemMemory();
```

Comment: Oh I see! So the compiler works like that! (I have come from C#)

Comment: Nitpick - I don't think it's *required* to declare a function before usage in C. In this case it is.

Answer (score 0):

You must "prototype" the function if you are going to be defining it below `int main() {}`:

```
long getTotalSystemMemory();

int main() {
    /* ....... */
    getTotalSystemMemory();
}

long getTotalSystemMemory() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

in c++ you must write the function before the functions that use it.

if you don't want to write the function in the top, you must put a  *[prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)*  before.
prototypes look like that:

`<return-value> <function name> (<parameters type>);`